# Opening Finder from terminal with file selected

Tags: macos, shell, terminal

I want to open Finder from the terminal with a specific file selected. I know that by using `open .` I can open the current directory in Finder, but I also want to select some file in the Finder window.

The basic thing I want to do is run a script that randomly selects a file among many in a folder and for that I need to open a new Finder window with the file selected.

Comment: try Open -R filepath

Answer (score 10):

For me, code below works fine.

```sh
open -R your-file-path
```

Comment: documentation from `--help`: `-R, --reveal` Selects in the Finder instead of opening.

Answer (score 7):

The `.` in your `open .` command just means path at current location (which would be a folder) so `open` decides that the correct application to use is Finder. If you were to do `open myTextFile.txt` which is at your current location in the terminal open will decide to use a text editor instead. You can however specify the application to open the file with by using the -a flag so your command would look like this: `open -a Finder myTextFile.txt`.

What Faisal suggested will also work, the -R flag is an equivalent to using  ⌘↩ (Command Return) in Spotlight.

this and some other nice shell tricks with the open command are described in this post: [Shell tricks: the OS X open command](http://brettterpstra.com/2014/08/06/shell-tricks-the-os-x-open-command/)

Comment: If you use open -a Finder file.zip the Finder will extract the file, so this is not what you want. "open -R file.zip" works nicely, though

Comment: This isn't the answer, the correct answer was given as a comment by faisal.
 "Open -R filepath"

Comment: This does not work for image files, `open -R {{filepath}}` does work correctly though.  `open -a Finder {{filepath}}` gives the error:  `The file ... couldn’t be opened because you don’t have permission to view it.`

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like that

`osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\"" -e activate -e "reveal POSIX file \"<your file path>\"" -e end tell`

Comment: Been trying to show a hidden file (specifically a .env file) in finder for a while now. This works like a charm!