# How to show class file in explorer in idea

Tags: intellij-idea

How to show class file (not java file) in explorer in IDEA?
When I select a java file, I want to position it in the explorer, I know in Eclipse it is easy, but what I should do in IDEA?

Comment: Please clarify what problem you are trying to solve. Do you want IDE to navigate you to the `.class` file containing the bytecode for the corresponding `.java` file you have open in the editor? Do you want IDE to open the folder with the `.class` file in the Windows Explorer? What for?

Comment: Yes, please clarify what do you want to do. If you have only `.java` file, the `.class` file may not yet exist if it wasn't compiled (or the target build directory was cleaned up afterwards).

What I can suggest you're really asking is to show the same `.java` or any other file in operation system explorer. To do this, right-click on the file and select "Show in Explorer" context menu point.

Comment: I  want IDE to open the folder with the .class file in the Windows Explorer

Comment: Using  Eclipse to navigate the .class file  within Windows/Macbook https://www.cnblogs.com/stevenlii/p/8513410.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with the [External Tool](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-tools-external-tools.html) like this:

[image: external tool]

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13680458/104891) describes what parameters to use for the `explorer.exe` to select the file.

Using IntelliJ IDEA macros the Arguments field will look like this:

`/select,"$OutputPath$\$FileDirRelativeToSourcepath$\$FileNameWithoutExtension$.class"`

It will open Explorer with the output file selected:

[image: output location]

For the source file located in `C:\work\attaches\hotswap-bug\src\foo\bazz\Another.java` the tool will select `C:\work\attaches\hotswap-bug\out\production\hotswap-bug\foo\bazz\Another.class` file.

This tool can be invoked from the editor right click menu while inside the source `.java` file:

[image: invoke tool]

You can also assign a keyboard shortcut to this tool or make an action in the toolbar for easier access.

Final result:

[image: .class file open in Explorer]

Just curious, what's the real world use case for this?

Comment: Thank you very much. It works!. I also have a MacBook, but I don't know how to set it too. Could you help me?

Comment: @steven I don't have Mac, sorry, but you can [try this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51186186/104891).